# Clear Non Removable Notifications

Tags: android, notifications, notification-listener

I am making notification blocker which removes selected applications Notifications.

I have used the snippet in my **Notification Listener Service** as,

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    if(SettingsActivity.SettingsInfo.getInt(sbn.getPackageName(), R.drawable.unblock)==R.drawable.block)
        {
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) 
               cancelNotification(sbn.getPackageName(), sbn.getTag(), sbn.getId());
            else 
               cancelNotification(sbn.getKey());
        }
}
```

But this code *only clears the cancellable* notifications. But I want to remove all notifications of the selected app(also system notifications). Is there any way to do this?

I tried *reflection method* too.

```
 NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        manager.cancel(sbn.getTag(), sbn.getId());
                        Class localClass = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager");
                        Method getService = localClass.getMethod("getService", new Class[]{String.class});
                        if (getService != null) {
                            Object result = getService.invoke(localClass, new Object[]{Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE});
                            if (result != null) {
                                IBinder binder = (IBinder) result;
                                final INotificationManager iNotificationManager = INotificationManager.Stub.asInterface(binder);
                                int uid = 0;
                                try {
                                    uid = this.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(sbn.getPackageName(), 0).uid;
                                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                iNotificationManager.cancelAllNotifications(sbn.getPackageName(), uid);
                            }
                        }
```

But I am getting **`Security Exception`**

`as Calling UID gave package owned by other UID`

For more details, I want to do *like*

> **App ->App Settings -> Notifications -> Block All**

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: if you want to cancel all notifications you can try `notificationManager.cancelAll();`

Comment: But I want to do it for particular app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response, From my research I got the solution

> to clear notifications with flag FLAG_NO_CLEAR

for api>25, You can **snooze** notification like

```
snoozeNotification(sbn.getKey(), Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

for api>23 and <26 , there is a method which can be used to **ovveride group key** and group them to your notifications,

```
statusbarnotification.setOverrideGroupKey("key");
```

for less api's,

You need **root access or system privileges** . Then you can use

```
iNotificationManager.cancelAllNotifications(sbn.getPackageName(), uid);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cancel notifications of another apps, you need to use 
 [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html)

It has the `cancelNotification` method:

```
public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {
    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
      cancelNotification(sbn.getKey());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it is working:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    // Store each StatusBarNotification object

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        cancelNotification(sbn.getPackageName(), sbn.getTag(), sbn.getId());
        Log.d("Cncel ","Cancel not");
    }
    else {
        cancelNotification(sbn.getKey());
        Log.d("key ","Cancel not key");
    }
}

@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    // Delete removed StatusBarNotification objects
}

}
```